# How can I allow postgresql connections from specific ip address?

Tags: networking, postgresql

I have a postgres database. I would like to allow connections to this database
from a specific machine.

I have installed postgresql-12 and have started the postgresql service on both machines.

I have added this line to my pg__hba.conf:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE           USER            ADDRESS               METHOD
host    test_db            nick            192.168.1.19/32       trust
```

I am able to get into test_db just fine from the machine that originally hosted the DB. On the other machine though, there is no sign of `test_db` anywhere. Both computers are connected to the same home network.

Comment: Do you have a firewall which blocks port 5432 and is Postgres bound to listen on all interfaces?